# How to convert from Properties file to CSV file which has multiple languages like hu?

Tags: java, locale, export-to-csv, properties-file, opencsv

In property file it looks like,

```
value1=CÍMSOR (NEM KÖTELEZŐ)
value2=NEM KÖTELEZŐ/NEM ALKALMAZHATÓ
```

I have loaded this in Java `.properties` which comes exactly like above, then the problem comes while storing to String. In both values 'Ő' comes as '?'.

I have to store it in a String and save all these values in CSV (comma separated) file.

First I am reading the property file

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new InputStreamReader(input, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

This part works properly.

Second reading the values

```
String value1 = prop.getProperty("value1");
```

`value1` comes like "4. CÍMSOR (NEM KÖTELEZ?)" instead of 'Ő' it comes as '?'

The third part is to add this values into CSV file,

```
OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(outputCSVLocation);
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stream, "UTF-8")));    
csvWriter.writeNext(value1);
```

Comment: looks like that your source file is not UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Its ISO-8859-1. I have converted till String part. I am trying to find the exact format to encode it in .csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer,
For conversion to String use this,

```
StringUtils.toEncodedString("".getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

For converting this values into csv use this below,

```
    OutputStream fileWriter = new FileOutputStream(outputCSVLocation);
    //Informing csv to encode in UTF-8
    byte[] enc = new byte[] { (byte)0xEF, (byte)0xBB, (byte)0xBF };
    fileWriter.write(enc);
    CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileWriter, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

So When I open file it comes in the language which was in the property file.

But again I got another issue,
When I read the csv file it comes with values like ?"header value" this that too for first  row first column value alone. This comes because of those 3 bytes for encoding which I have added.

Any idea to fix this ??

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your input Properties file is really ISO-8859-1? If so then you should be loading the properties with:

```
prop.load(new InputStreamReader(input, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
```

Or - you can call the default Properties `load(InputStream)` which makes the assumption that the input stream is ISO-8859-1 character set, and allows for other unicode characters as escape sequences of format `\uNNNN`.

Comment: Yes I am sure. Its ISO-8859-1 but if i use the above code it comes in gibirish not coming as expected. But while using UTF-8 its coming properly.